# Confusion related to gaussian distribution

Tags: normal-distribution

I was reading this [paper](http://jmlr.org/proceedings/papers/v28/wytock13.pdf) where it had a gaussian distribution model.

I mean gaussian is given by

$P(y) = \frac{e^{-\frac{1}{2}(y -\mu)^T \Sigma^{-1}(y -\mu)}}{2\pi^{n/2}|\Sigma|^{1/2}}$

But is

$\frac{e^{-(y -\mu)^T \Sigma^{-1}(y -\mu)}}{2\pi^{n}|\Sigma|}$ Gaussian as well?

The paper used their model saying the gaussian had the above form. It is valid?

Comment: I don't understand the question (even after looking at the paper). Your $P(y)$ is a decent, normalized, multivariate, Gaussian. The next equation is its square. So normalization is lost in the second equation.

Comment: @lcv. That's what I am not getting. In the paper, they have modeled like in the second case and said that it is gaussian. In their case the mean of the distribution is $-\Lambda^{-1}\Theta^Tx$ and precision matrix is $\Lambda$. And they have something like $exp^{-y^T \Lambda y...}$. The bottom line is they haven't included the 1/2 fraction in the exponent and saying that it is gaussian. Is it right?

Comment: do you refer to eq. (1) of the paper? That one is perfectly normalized. I can post an answer when I get to a real computer

Comment: @lcv. Yeah I mean equation 1. How come that is gaussian. They haven't included the 1/2 term in the exponent

Comment: @lcv. I am waiting for your answer

Answer (score 1):

I think the equation we are talking about is

$$
p(y) = \frac{1}{Z}\exp \{ -y^T \Lambda y - 2 x^T\Theta y \}
$$

This is a perfectly normalized, multivariate Gaussian and the normalization factor is precisely $Z$, the partition function. Indeed $Z$ *is* defined by the normalization

$$
\int p(y) dy =1 .
$$

The integration can be performed *completing the square*, i.e. writing

$$
p(y) =  \frac{1}{Z}\exp\{ - (y-y_0)^T \Lambda (y-y_0) + y_0 \Lambda y_0 \}
$$
by choosing $y_0=\Lambda^{-1}\Theta^T x$ so that the term linear in $y$ matches. You can now change variable $y'=y-y_0$ and the normalization condition reads

$$
\frac{1}{Z} \exp\{x^T \Theta \Lambda^{-1} \Theta^T x \} \int \exp\{- y'^T \Lambda y'\} dy'=1 
$$
The integration over $y'$ gives

$$
\int \exp\{- y'^T \Lambda y'\} dy'=\sqrt{\frac{\pi^n}{\det{\Lambda}}}
$$

Finally the normalization is
$$
\frac{1}{Z} \exp\{x^T \Theta \Lambda^{-1} \Theta^T x \}  \sqrt{\frac{\pi^n}{\det{\Lambda}}} = 1
$$

i.e.
$$
\frac{1}{Z} = \exp\{-x^T \Theta \Lambda^{-1} \Theta^T x \} \sqrt{\det{\Lambda}} \pi^{-n/2}
$$

which should be Eq. (2) of your paper. The, unimportant, numerical constant $c$ in the paper is $\pi^{-n/2}$ but in Eq. (2) they forgot the sqrt term on $\det{\Lambda}$ (probably a typo).

You can compute the Gaussian integral yourself looking at this link

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral#n-dimensional_with_linear_term

Comment: I would doubt that they made a typo. I am still thinking why they don't have the sqrt term on $det \Lambda$

Comment: If you look at the paper it's already published and their whole work afterwards is dependent on just $|\Lambda|$ not $|\Lambda|^{1/2}$. Any insights

Comment: The calculation is before your eyes, you can check it yourself (don't trust the first person you meet on the internet). Anyway It's well known that for real Gaussian integral you get the sqrt. The reason is that $\int e^{-x^2/c} dx = \sqrt{\pi/c}$.

Comment: So you mean the paper is incorrect. If that was the case, why was it accepted in a top conference at the first place? I just don't get it

Comment: Why is the panda endangered? In any case no, I just mean you can check it yourself and convince of what is right.